# Apex of a cyclically ordered group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Does it make sense to introduce the new definition?

**Definition 2.1**. An element $\pi$ of a cyclically ordered group is an *apex* of the group iff $\pi = - \pi \ne 0$.

Considering an element $x$ of a cyclically ordered group is *positive* (*negative*) iff $[0, x, -x]$
($[0, -x, x]$) ([Positive and negative elements of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2213048/427611)),
an *apex* is not positive and not negative.

It looks like an *apex* has some interesting properties
(I am using the [Cycle notation for cyclic orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236651/427611) wherever it is convenient):

**Lemma 2.1** (well-known). An *apex* of a cyclically ordered group is unique.

Proof.

- Assuming there are two apexes $\pi$, $\pi'$, and $[0, \pi, \pi']$;
- Compatibility with $\pi$: $[\pi, 0, \pi + \pi']$;
- Compatibility with $\pi'$: $[\pi', \pi + \pi', 0]$;
- 4-Cycle: $[\pi, 0, \pi + \pi'] \land [\pi', \pi + \pi', 0] \iff [0, \pi', \pi + \pi', \pi]$;
- $[0, \pi', \pi + \pi', \pi] \implies [0, \pi', \pi]$, contradiction.

**Corollary 2.1.** An element of a cyclically ordered group is either $0$, *positive*, *negative*, or the *apex*.

**Lemma 2.2.** If $\pi$ is the *apex* of a cyclically ordered group, then an element $x$ is *positive* (*negative*) $\iff [0, x, \pi]$ ($[0, \pi, x]$).

Proof:

1. $[0, x, \pi] \implies [0, x, -x]$:

   - Negation: $[0, x, \pi] \iff [0, -\pi, -x] \iff [0, \pi, -x]$;
   - Transitivity: $[0, x, \pi] \land [0, \pi, -x] \implies [0, x, -x]$;
2. $[0, \pi, x] \implies [0, -x, x]$:

   - Negation: $[0, \pi, x] \iff [0, -x, -\pi] \iff  [0, -x, \pi]$;
   - Applying 1: $[0, -x, \pi] \implies [0, -x, x]$;
3. $[0, x, -x] \implies [0, x, \pi]$:

   - Assuming $[0, \pi, x]$ ($x \ne 0$, $x \ne -x$);
   - Applying 2: $[0, \pi, x] \implies [0, -x, x]$, contradiction;
4. $[0, -x, x] \implies [0, \pi, x]$:

   - Assuming $[0, x, \pi]$ ($x \ne 0$, $x \ne -x$);
   - Applying 1: $[0, x, \pi] \implies [0, x, -x]$, contradiction.

**Lemma 2.3.** If $\pi$ is the *apex* of a cyclically ordered group, then an element $x$ is *positive* (*negative*) $\iff [\pi, -x, x]$ ($[\pi, x, -x]$).

Proof:

1. $[0, x, -x] \implies [\pi, -x, x]$:

   - Lemma 2.2: $[0, x, -x] \iff [0, x, \pi]$;
   - Negation: $[0, x, \pi] \iff [0, -\pi, -x] \iff [0, \pi, -x]$;
   - 4-Cycle: $[0, x, \pi] \land [0, \pi, -x] \iff [0, x, \pi, -x]$;
   - $[0, x, \pi, -x] \implies [\pi, -x, x]$;
2. $[0, -x, x] \implies [\pi, x, -x]$:

   - Applying 1: $[0, -x, x] \implies [\pi, x, -x]$;
3. $[\pi, -x, x] \implies [0, x, -x]$:

   - Assuming $[0, -x, x]$ ($x \ne -x$);
   - Applying 2: $[0, -x, x] \implies [\pi, x, -x]$, contradiction;
4. $[\pi, x, -x] \implies [0, -x, x]$:

   - Assuming $[0, x, -x]$ ($x \ne -x$);
   - Applying 1: $[0, x, -x] \implies [\pi, -x, x]$, contradiction.

**Lemma 2.4.** If $\pi$ is the *apex* of a cyclically ordered group, then $(x + \pi)$ is *negative* (*positive*) for any *positive* (*negative*) $x$.

Proof:

- Lemma 2.2: $x$ is positive $\iff [0, x, \pi]$;
- Cyclicity: $[0, x, \pi] \iff [\pi, 0, x]$;
- Compatibility with $\pi$: $[\pi, 0, x] \implies [0, \pi, x + \pi]$;
- Lemma 2.2: $[0, \pi, x + \pi] \iff (x + \pi)$ is negative.

Could somebody verify the statements, please?