# Compatibility with multiplication of a cyclic order on a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory

Considering a linear order on the additive group of a ring is compatible with multiplication if:

- $a < b \implies ax < bx$ and $xa < xb$ for any positive $x$,

we could define compatibility for a cyclically ordered additive group in a similar way:

A cyclic order on the additive group of a ring is compatible with multiplication if:

- $[a, b, c] \implies [ax, bx, cx]$ and $[xa, xb, xc]$ for any positive $x$.

([Positive and negative elements of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2213048/427611))

One can notice the induced cyclic order C of any *linearly* ordered ring L is compatible with multiplication:

- Definition of C: $[a, b, c] \iff a < b < c \lor b < c < a \lor c < a < b$;
- Compatibility with multiplication of L: $a < b < c \lor b < c < a \lor c < a < b \implies ax < bx < cx \lor bx < cx < ax \lor cx < ax < bx$ for a positive $x$;
- From the properties of the [Natural cut of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3207182/427611):
  $x$ is positive in L $\iff x$ is positive in C;
- Definition of C: $ax < bx < cx \lor bx < cx < ax \lor cx < ax < bx \iff [ax, bx, cx]$.

It looks like the only rings with *non-linearly* cyclically ordered additive groups (with three or more elements) compatible with multiplication in this way are $\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_4$. Is this correct?

My attempt to prove it:

Lemma. In a ring with cyclically ordered additive group compatible with multiplication:
if both $a$ and $b$ are positive or negative, then $ab$ is positive;
if one of $a$ or $b$ is positive, and another one is negative, then $ab$ is negative.

Proof:

1. Case $a,b$ are positive $\implies ab$ is positive:

   - Definition: $a$ is positive $\iff [0, a, -a]$;
   - Compatibility with multiplication on $b$: $[0, a, -a] \implies [0, ab, -ab]$;
   - Definition: $[0, ab, -ab] \iff ab$ is positive.
2. Case $a$ is negative, $b$ is positive $\implies ab$ is negative:

   - Definition: $a$ is negative $\iff [0, -a, a]$;
   - Compatibility with multiplication on $b$: $[0, -a, a] \implies [0, -ab, ab]$;
   - Definition: $[0, ab, -ab] \iff ab$ is positive.
3. Case $a$ is positive, $b$ is negative $\implies ab$ is negative:

   - Same as Case 2.
4. Case $a$ is negative, $b$ is negative $\implies ab$ is positive:

   - Definition: $a$ is negative $\iff [0, -a, a]$;
   - $-b$ is positive;
   - Compatibility with $-b$: $[0, -a, a] \implies [0, ab, -ab]$;
   - Definition: $[0, ab, -ab] \iff ab$ is positive.

Now, back to the main statement:

- From the property of [Quadrants of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3230720/427611):
  if there are two different positive elements, then every quadrant of the group is not empty;
- Taking $a$ from the first quadrant, and $b$ from the second quadrant:

  - $(a + a)b = a(b + b)$;
  - $a + a$ is positive, $b + b$ is negative;
  - $(a + a)b$ is positive, but $a(b + b)$ is negative, contradiction.

Thus, there cannot be more than one positive element in order for non-linearly cyclically ordered additive group of a ring to be compatible with multiplication.

Are there better approaches for compatibility with multiplication for rings?