# Multiples of infinite ordinals

Tags: order-theory, ordinals

There is an intuitive approach to arithmetic of infinite ordinals:

"After all natural numbers comes the first infinite ordinal, $\omega$, and after that come $\omega + 1$, $\omega + 2$, $\omega + 3$, and so on ... After all of these come $\omega\cdot2$ (which is $\omega + \omega$), $\omega\cdot2+1$, $\omega\cdot2+2$, and so on, then $\omega\cdot3$, and then later on $\omega\cdot4$."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Ordinals_extend_the_natural_numbers.

However, before claiming we have an infinite set of multiplies $\omega\cdot n$ we need to make sure they are all unique.

Considering the [Quadrants of a cyclically ordered group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3230720/427611) we can say that all natural numbers (excluding $0$) belong to the first quadrant of the group:

- $0 < \mathbb N < \frac{a}{2}$, whrere $a$ is the (imaginary) apex of the cyclic order of $\mathbb N$.

Applying the definition of $\omega$ we can say that $\frac{a}{2} = \omega$.

From this point of view:

- $\omega\cdot2 = 2\frac{a}{2} = a$;
- $\omega\cdot3 = 3\frac{a}{2} = -\frac{a}{2} = -\omega$;
- $\omega\cdot4 = 4\frac{a}{2} = 2a = 0$.

Thus, we only have four distinct multiples of $\omega$:

- $\omega\cdot n = \{0, \pm\omega, 2\omega\}$.

Would it be a valid statement?
If not, what is the main difficulty of the approach?

Comment: I'm not sure how cyclically ordered groups are relevant to discussing ordinals.  Ordinals are ordered (honestly--not just cyclically), but they don't form a group.  In fact, even if you impose an upper bound (so that they form a set) and throw in negatives, they still don't form a group:  e.g. 1 + $\omega$ = $\omega$, but $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: @RaviFernando Any linear order is cyclic. When talking about multiplication on ordinals we assume an algebraic structure. I am not saying ordinals is a (semi)group. I am simply extending the logic of natural numbers onto a larger structure, suggesting that $4\omega$ may not be a unique number.

Comment: @RaviFernando it's even worse than that - since ordinal addition is non-cancellative (e.g. $1+\omega=0+\omega$ but $1\not=0$), there is no way to "throw in negatives" without destroying the structure completely. More precisely (and ignoring set/class issues), any monoid homomorphism from the ordinals to a group $G$ has trivial image.

Comment: @AlexC "I am simply extending the logic of natural numbers onto a larger structure" At present, all you're doing is arguing by vague analogy. You need to define the various things you're using precisely: what exactly is the larger object you're situating $\mathbb{N}$ inside? You seem to want this to be a cyclically ordered group, but then (per my comment) it won't have any good relationship with the ordinals.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My question is why we assume that all the numbers $n\omega$ are unique. And what is the main problem for them to not be unique. I simply tried to bring an example of such a case. I am not sure why it is such a bad (-2) question.

Comment: @AlexC We **don't** assume that they're all unique, we **prove** that from the formal definitions. You're claiming some connection between how the ordinals are actually defined and behave, and this particular algebraic picture you have, but that connection needs to be justified (and in fact it's not there).

Comment: Even ignoring that, you seem to be assuming that in this "cyclically ordered ordinals structure" you have in mind, $\mathbb{N}$ constitutes a whole quadrant. Why should that be? E.g. $\mathbb{N}$ embeds appropriately into the group of integer-coefficient polynomials with respect to addition, which when construed as a genuinely ordered group has two nonempty quadrants with $\mathbb{N}$('s image) being *properly* contained in one. Basically, you're implicitly making several unjustified assumptions here, to the point that I'm not sure this question is really answerable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber $\mathbb N$ belongs to the first quadrant since $2n$ is positive for any natural $n$. Is it not correct?

Comment: @AlexC First of all, the first quadrant *of what*? What is the larger algebraic structure you have in mind? It can't be the ordinals, since they don't form a cyclically orderable group, or even a group, or even a cancellative monoid, in the first place. Second, even if we are looking at some cyclically orderable group with $\mathbb{N}$ contained in it, why should $\mathbb{N}$ be the *entirety* of its first quadrant (which you need in order to argue that anything special should happen when you add $\omega$ to itself)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber The larger algebraic structures I meant are $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, and $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb N$ is entirely in the first quadrant by the definition of the first quadrant for the listed structures.

Comment: @AlexC Sure, but none of those structures is the ordinals! So those are each totally irrelevant. What precise larger structure do you have in mind which **does** contain $\omega$ as well as each specific natural number, and to which ideas about cyclically ordered groups are applicable?

Comment: Moreover, you're misreading my comment: I wasn't objecting to $\mathbb{N}$ being contained in a single quadrant, I was objecting to the assumption that it **fills up** a whole quadrant! You need something like that to argue that you "wrap around" when you add $\omega$ to itself (again, see a couple comments above re: $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am not extending ordinals from $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb R$. I am using the properties of $\mathbb N$. The notion of quadrants can easily be extended to semigroups.

Comment: @AlexC The notions can, but their properties can't. The ordinals (ignoring set/class issues) form an ordered *non-cancellative* semigroup with exactly one nonempty quadrant. (The "non-cancellative" bit is crucial, since it [prevents natural attempts to "groupify" things by formally adding inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group): every semigroup homomorphism from the ordinals to some group has trivial image. So this is truly an unfixable problem.) You **really** need to precisely define everything you're looking at and justify your various algebraic claims.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The very first picture on the Wikipedia page shows ordinals as a spiral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number. They fill all the quadrants on it. The structure is pretty close to a circle to me. Do you think it is a misleading picture?

Comment: @AlexC I don't think it's misleading since I don't think it's meant to be taken that literally - it's just supposed to be a reasonably-compact picture (basically "folding up" a line so it's easier to fit into a smaller image). Regardless, a spiral isn't the same as a circle, and visual analogies are not at all the same as precise mathematical definitions. (Also note that in that diagram the natural numbers wind up filling all four quadrants! So *even if* we take it overly-literally and turn the spiral into a circle, it doesn't give the picture you describe.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is there a name for the numbers $n\omega$ in the context I use them?

Comment: @AlexC Maybe, but I'm still not sure what that context actually is. Again, can you precisely define the algebraic structure you're looking at? For example, I see no reason why $\omega\cdot3=-\omega$ except that you've declared it to be so.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The numbers are multiples of the half-apex. The multiplication follows the definition of an apex: $2a = 0$.

Comment: @AlexC And why is $\omega$ the half-apex of this structure, or are you just declaring it to be?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $n < \omega \iff (0, n, \omega)$; $n$ is in the first quadrant $\iff (0, n, \frac{a}{2})$.

Comment: @AlexC No, that second claim **already assumes** that $\omega={a\over 2}$. Is that a starting assuption you're making?

Comment: @NoahSchweber If we extend $\mathbb N$ with an apex $a$, then $\omega$ (the smallest number such that $n < \omega$ for all $n$ of $\mathbb N$) must be $\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: @AlexC Why should that be the case? Why couldn't the apex  be much larger than $\omega\cdot 2$? You seem to be assuming - as I pointed out before - that $\mathbb{N}$ "fills out" the entire first quadrant. But there's no a priori reason for it to do so.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry. I did not understand your meaning of "fills out". I thought you meant "densely" or "continuously" fills. Does it mean $\mathbb N$ must be between $0$ and an occurrence of any rational fraction of $a$ in the cyclic order?

Comment: @AlexC I mean, why can't there be things bigger than any element of $\mathbb{N}$ but smaller than ${a\over 2}$? (That is, some $u$ such that $[0,n,u]$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but also $[0, u+1, {a\over 2}]$.) We can have this situation occur in cyclically ordered groups with all four quadrants nonempty into which $\mathbb{N}$ emebds as a sub-monoid, so what *else* is going on here that guarantees $\omega={a\over 2}$? Or, are you assuming $\omega={a\over 2}$ right away?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes. Thank you. I think, I understand the cyclic structure of ordinals now. Should I remove the question as a negative value for the site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111605/discussion-between-alex-c-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: @AlexC I would like to point out that $4\omega$ is not a unique number, as it is equal to $\omega$ and $n\omega$ for any finite ordinal $n$. I assume you mean $\omega\cdot4$.

Comment: @L.McDonald What do **you** mean by $4\omega$? There is no $4\omega$ in my question. The context where $4\omega$ appeared in the comments is closed long time ago by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, there is no group (cyclically ordered or otherwise) that contains 0, 1, and $\omega$ and whose operation is compatible with ordinal addition.  Ordinals just don't fit into the framework of cyclically ordered groups.

I would recommend looking at the definition of the ordinals $\omega n$ for $n$ a natural number, and the definition of the linear order on ordinals.  It should be easy to see that $\omega n < \omega (n+1)$ for all n:  the latter contains the former as an element.  In particular, this proves that the ordinals $\omega n$ are all distinct.

Comment: Accepting with many thanks to Noah Schweber for the help in the comments.